# How does Spring Boot know whether MessageMapping specifies a Jms Queue or a Websocket topic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-jms

I have a Controller bean with a method such as

```
@MessageMapping("${my.topic}")
public void receiveCommand(Message content) {
    log.info("Received command: " + content);
}
```

And I also inject a `SimpMessagingTemplate` and a `JmsMessagingTemplate` into this controller. I believe the problem with my `receiveCommand` method is that Spring is expecting this to be a JMS message and not a WebSocket message. However this seems impossible to determine, how can I make sure that this method corresponds to a WebSocket topic and not a JMS queue?

My application is annotated with `@EnableJms` and `@EnableWebSocket` and works well for receiving JMS messages and sending WebSocket messages via STOMP, but doesn't seem to be able to receive WebSocket messages.

The message imports are as follows on my Controller.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
```

I also have another method that uses a JmsListener that works, so I am wondering if this is somehow picked up by Spring on the classpath and overrides the MessageMapping to be a JMS queue name.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${my.destination}")
public void receiveMessage(String content) {
   System.out.println("Jms message: " + content); 
}
```

I do not see any stack traces or errors when running a unit test that looks like the following.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate websocket;

@Value("${my.topic}")
private String topic;

@Test
public void shouldReceiveCommandMessages() throws IOException {
    URL url = Resources.getResource("command.json");
    String json = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
    this.websocket.convertAndSend(topic, json);
}
```

Which is within a larger `SpringBootTest` that works for testing the Jms sending and receiving.

Comment: Your question is not clear; the `Message` type depends on the `import` statement. `@MessageMappng` is not for JMS. You can't have a single method that consumes both types. You would need 2 methods, with one of them fully qualifying the type. The templates make no difference; they are for outbound messages.

Comment: are u receiving any exception?

Comment: @GaryRussell I've added more detail to try and make the question more clear. Can you clarify what you mean by fully qualifying the type? Do you mean the message type?

Comment: I meant if you explicitly listened for `javax.jms.Message` in your JmsListener, you would have to qualify one of them with the package name. `>is that Spring is expecting this to be a JMS message` - no; you have the correct import for a Messaging `Message<?>`. So that is not the problem. The `@JmsListener` won't interfere.

Comment: Any guess why this unit test wouldn't call the `receiveCommand`? From what I can tell it should be configured so that they send and receive on the same topic and are injected with the same values. Also seems to not call this method on an external web ui that uses SockJS with a STOMP socket but this same UI is able to receive the messages sent from the SimpMessagingTemplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SIMP template is for sending data out to connected clients; to send data into the controller you should use the [STOMP Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-client).

> 4.4.6. Send Messages
>
> What if you want to send messages to connected clients from any part of the application? Any application component can send messages to the "brokerChannel". The easiest way to do that is to have a SimpMessagingTemplate injected, and use it to send messages. Typically it should be easy to have it injected by type, for example:
>
> 4.4.15. STOMP Client
>
> Spring provides a STOMP over WebSocket client and a STOMP over TCP client.

```
@Controller
class Listener {

    @MessageMapping("/string")
    public void handle(String in) {
        System.out.println("STOMP Received: " + in);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "so50614472")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println("JMS Received: " + in);
    }

}
```

and

```
STOMP Received: foo
JMS Received: bar
```

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell this in combination with a problem in the prefix e.g. `/app/foo` calls a `MessageMapping("/foo")` fixed it for me.

Comment: @Gary Russell I am just wondering if there is any special difference in SimpMessagingTemplate and JmsMessagingTemplate. Or if one have any priority over other in any case.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. The difference is one is for sending to a web socket; the other is for sending to a JMS broker - ask a new question if you need more clarification.